# Plotting Binding probability martix in R

Tags: r, matrix, plot, binding, probability

I have binding probability matrix with dim =  4461, 429. The matrix does not have either column name or row name. I would like to plot this binding probability matrix, what should be the best way to visualize and plot this matrix.

Probability Binding Matrix

```
     V1         V2      V3        V4        V5        V6
1 0.1302677 0.1338888 0.1375044 0.1411146 0.1447193 0.1483186 
2 0.9863382 0.9848000 0.9832758 0.9817656 0.9802694 0.9787871 
3.0000000 1.0000000 1.000000 0.9999999 0.9999992 0.9999932 
4 0.9999403 0.9999488 0.999957 0.9999577 0.9999584 0.9999590
```

as output I would like to get curve  that shows the Binding probability of a particular position.

Comment: Please edit your question to include 1) your matrix (or a fake version of it) in code form and 2) your expected output: what plot are you trying to get? A heat map, something else?

Comment: @Andrea M I have edited the question as requested.

Comment: Thanks. For those of us who are not familiar with these types of matrices, what does each row and column represent? And could you post a link to a similar plot?